# Generic type inference with dependent types in Go

Tags: go, generics

I want to have helpers for big maths from `big` package. One of them is `IsZero` which accepts `big.(Int|Float|Rat)` and returns `true` if this big number equals to zero and `false` if not.

I did it that way:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

type Target interface {
    big.Int | big.Float | big.Rat
}

type Comparable[T Target] interface {
    Cmp(*T) int
}

func IsZero[C Comparable[T], T Target](a C) bool {
    var t T

    return a.Cmp(&t) == 0
}
```

And it works if I specify generic arguments explicitly:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsZero[Comparable[big.Int], big.Int](big.NewInt(0)))
}
```

But if I try to make Go infer them for me, it doesn't work:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsZero(big.NewInt(0)))
}
```

```
./prog.go:25:20: cannot infer T (prog.go:18:30)
```

---

Is there a possible workaround for this?

Comment: "Is there a possible workaround for this?" No, except hope inference will be smarter in the next Go version.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there a possible workaround for this?" No, except hope inference will be smarter in the next Go version. –
> Volker

Your can only simplify `IsZero` function:

```
func IsZero[T Target](a Comparable[T]) bool {
    var t T

    return a.Cmp(&t) == 0
}
```

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsZero[big.Int](big.NewInt(0)))

    var b Comparable[big.Int] = big.NewInt(0)
    fmt.Println(IsZero(b))
}
```